# How to make Retrofit model with several internal lists

Tags: android, arrays, json, list, retrofit2

I want to create a model for the following Json, and when I use the [jsonschema2poj](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website the returned model is not correct And I do not have access to `Id`, `job` and `Titles`. I use Retrofit for REST API.
Please help me make the right model.

```
{
  "res": [
    [
      {
        "name": "tom",
        "lname": "ford",
        "Status": 3
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Title1": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "Title2": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "Title3": "CCC"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": "123",
        "job": "Doctor"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can use this plugin in android studio https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator

Answer (score 0):

make pojo class like this way..

```
public class ResItemItem{

@SerializedName("Status")
private int status;

@SerializedName("lname")
private String lname;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

public void setStatus(int status){
    this.status = status;
}

public int getStatus(){
    return status;
}

public void setLname(String lname){
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getLname(){
    return lname;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

}

public class ResponseData{

@SerializedName("res")
private List<List<ResItemItem>> res;

public void setRes(List<List<ResItemItem>> res){
    this.res = res;
}

public List<List<ResItemItem>> getRes(){
    return res;
}

}
```

and pass ResponeData pojo class into retrofit api respone.

i hope you know all things into retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a generic mechanism where there are no defined keys for the arrays, you can use an array of `Map<String,String>` if there are multiple items in `res` array and then wrap it inside another object. This would essentially give a `List<Map<String, String>>`. Your class can be:

```
public class ResultObject {
    // considering that the res object has multiple
    // array of nested array of objects, if not then
    // use just Map<String, String> without the List<>

    List<Map<String, String>> mMapString;  

    public Map<String, String> getMapForIndex(int index) throws IllegalAccessException {
        if (mMapString == null || index > mMapString.size()) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("map is null or index is too large");
        }
        return mMapString.get(index);
    }
}
```

and your parent class would be:

```
public class ParentObject {
    @SerializedName("res")
    @Expose
    ResultObject mResult;

    public ResultObject getResult() {
        return mResult;
    }
}
```

I however, recommend a cleaner JSON structure, named individually if you can control the backend flow as well.

Comment: You can access it by using GSON library
`final MyUser user = new MyUser();`
`final Map<String, String> mMap = result.getMapForIndex(0)`
`for (Map.Entry<String, String> map : mMap.entrySet()){`
    `user.name = map.getKey("user") != null ? map.getValue() : "";`
    `....`
`}` or with `try-catch` blocks when on `getKey("name");`